# ArrayCollection not updated via ItemRenderer (CheckBox) in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I am having problems to update my ArrayCollection which initially populates my datagrid. In my case the dataprovider consists of `True` and `False` as String. These come from my database. I set the dataProvider of my datagrid to the ArrayCollection and I render the field in a checkBox in the datagrid. The checkbox is ticked correctly upon display. But if I tick/untick the checkbox again and try to take a look at the ArrayCollection, I notice that the ArrayCollection remains unchanged. I still get the old values.

Can someone guide me through as to what I am missing in my code? Below is the code for my datagrid.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" dataProvider="myArrayCollection" fontSize="9" enabled="true" x="20" y="20" width="217" height="60">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected" width="20" headerText="MyField" dataField="MY_FIELD">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:CheckBox selected="{data.MY_FIELD == 'false' ? false : true}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                    </mx:HBox>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your CheckBox with this:

```
<s:CheckBox selected="{data.MY_FIELD == 'false' ? false : true}" change="data.MY_FIELD = !data_MY_FIELD" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

This should flip the value whenever the user changes the state of the CheckBox.

Comment: MY_FIELD comes from my database query which populates an ArrayCollection in Flex. The ArrayCollection is set as [Bindable]. But still it does not work?

Any idea

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: I have a question still. My values are coming as 'true' or 'false' from my data provider. But if I check or uncheck a checkbox, the value that it returns is YES or NO instead of returning true of false itself. This is very strange. Can you advise that is going wrong here?

Thanks